# how can i play sound in android

Tags: java, android

I wrote simplw android program to play sound and it's not working . Have no idea why .
maybe it's related to the fact that i have question mark near mymp3 file ( under raw directory ).
I tried few options without any suseess .

Attached below is my code , thanks in advance .
xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:background="#CFEC89"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/sound"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Sound"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#EAE3E3"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

main acitivy java

```
package com.example.playsound;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

        // define my variables

        Button sound;
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cat);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mp.start();

        }
    }
```

and my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.playsound">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PlaySound">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, delete your `TextView` it could lay over your `Button`. That's why you probably can't click it.

Paste that in your class:

```
package com.example.playsound;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cat);

        final Button sound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sound);

        sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
     }
}
```

For the future, you need to define your variables in the `OnCreate` and not above.